# "Network Link Conditioner" cannot be loaded (Catalina)

Tags: xcode, macos

Opening it from System Settings - it says it can't be loaded.
Doesnt show up in Xcode .
Any clue? I went thru everything I could find about this

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it work again in Catalina you have to remove the existing Network Link Conditioner from System Preferences and then download it again from [Additional Tool](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?q=Additional%20Tools) for your current Xcode version.

Answer (score -1):

There is a Network Link Conditioner in iOS developer settings on the device...